# ReflectionException Class does not exist happens on git branch switch Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

So I read like 100 post about this before deciding on creating this issue.

This problem is actually very specific and it's 100% reproducable.

I created a git branch lets call it `storeUpdate`, and in this branch I created a file called

```
app/Http/Controllers/Admin/BatchUpdateStoresController.php
```

which has the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\BatchUpdateStores;

class BatchUpdateStoresController extends Controller
```

and I've added it to the routes.php file:

```
app/Http/routes.php|214| $api->put('stores', 'Admin\BatchUpdateStoresController@update');
app/Http/routes.php|215| $api->post('stores', 'Admin\BatchUpdateStoresController@upload');
```

also the relevant part in my composer file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php",
        "tests/Helpers/",
        "tests/Traits/"
    ]
},
```

However, when I switch the branch to another git branch, and I try to run `php artisan`, I get this error:

> [ReflectionException]   Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BatchUpdateStoresController does not exist

I find the above error interesting, as indeed that file doesn't exist (notice the actual file is `app/Http/Controllers/Admin/BatchUpdateStoresController.php`, so `app` != `App`, but aren't I already taking care of this in the `psr-4` section of my composer.json file?

Ideas?

## what i tried

all the usual stuff including:

- `composer dump-autoload`
- `composer update`
- `composer update --no-scripts`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan api:clear`
- `php artisan route:clear`

## stacktrace

```
ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BatchUpdateStoresController does not exist in /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:749 
Stack trace: #0 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(749): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Http\\Contro...') 
#1 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(644): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array) 
#2 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array) 
#3 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Route.php(320): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Contro...') 
#4 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Route.php(182): Dingo\Api\Routing\Route->makeControllerInstance() 
#5 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Route.php(165): Dingo\Api\Routing\Route->mergeControllerProperties() 
#6 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Route.php(144): Dingo\Api\Routing\Route->setupRouteProperties(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route)) 
#7 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(652): Dingo\Api\Routing\Route->__construct(Object(Dingo\Api\Routing\Adapter\Laravel), Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route)) 
#8 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(714): Dingo\Api\Routing\Router->createRoute(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route)) #9 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(744): Dingo\Api\Routing\Router->getRoutes() 
#10 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/bootstrap/cache/routes.php(17): Dingo\Api\Routing\Router->setAdapterRoutes(Array) 
#11 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(58): require('/Users/Shared/d...') 
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)) 
#13 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(808): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)) 
#14 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(757): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->fireAppCallbacks(Array) 
#15 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot() 
#16 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)) 
#17 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(267): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array) 
#18 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(113): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap() 
#19 /Users/Shared/dev/php/toters-api/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #20
```

h2. udpdate

based on [Edwards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8256132/eder-soares) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060474/766570) the following worked:

1. if you go to the git branch that doesn't have that class.. by definition, *any* `php artisan` will blow up, so then you already don't have access to some php artisan commands such as `php artisan route:clear`
2. therefore, go back to the original branch that has the above class and make sure `php artisan` runs
3. run `php artisan route:clear`
4. switch branches
5. profit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `php artisan route:clear` if don't solve, put your complete exception.

Comment: you are right! but the sequence of events is tricky.. i'll put the details in my question (credit goes to you though)

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## how to do it without php artisan

since php artisan is already jammed, you should simply delete `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` (ie in case you don't want to switch branches)

*note:* after you switch branches, you'll have to run 
`php artisan api:cache` or else it will complain that there are no routes