# Class hash does not exist laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm facing issue of "Class hash does not exist". I know there are same question related this but these are not enough for me. Here I'm loading routes as per user device. As per mobile I using different routes as shown below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    if(SiteHelpers::isMobileViewEnabled() == true && Mobile::isMobile() == true && Mobile::isTablet() == false){

        require app_path('Http/Routes/mui.php');

    }else{

        require app_path('Http/Routes/desktop.php');
    }

...
```

Here is SiteHelper code

```
public static function isMobileViewEnabled()
{
    $isEnabled = false;
    $user = Auth::user();
    $getEnabled = DB::table('setting')->where('setting_name', 'Mobile UI')->first();
    if(isset($getEnabled) && $getEnabled->setting_value==1){
        $isEnabled = true;
    }
    return $isEnabled;

}
```

When I use

> Auth::user()

Than I'm getting error

> Class hash does not exist [image]

I don't know whats going wrong, Please let me know where I making mistake.

Comment: Where have you used Hash? wherever you have used make sure in top after namespace `use Hash;`

Comment: Yeah!  @DilipHirapara I'm using Hash top of the SiteHelpers.

Comment: Try this use Hash; or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141040/uncaught-reflectionexception-class-hash-does-not-exist-in-envoyer-deploy

Comment: You seem to have the required provider there in the list. Try clearing services cache file https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-class-hash-does-not-exist

Comment: @Sehdev No its not working for me. When I'm tryting to clear cache its throwing same error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the required provider there in the list. Try clearing services cache file

Comment: No its not working for me. When I'm tryting to clear cache its throwing same error

Comment: You try check in config/app.php. Have you updated it? Like: `'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,`

Comment: Yes, I have added required service provider in config/app.php.

Comment: I have refer to some similar issues. Do you have the php mbstring/PDO etc libraries installed properly (have you updated your server recently?) Make sure you have everything from. If you are using Laravel 5.2. Can you refer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer for your question but I think it will create issue for you later on so,replace this

```
if(!is_null($getEnabled) && $getEnabled->setting_value==1){
        $isEnabled = true;
    }
```

with

```
if(isset($getEnabled) && $getEnabled->setting_value==1){
        $isEnabled = true;
    }
```

Because `$getEnabled` is always set.